# What model could you use with a non-binary categorical response variable?

Tags: predictive-models

Sorry if this is a simple question, I couldn't find satisfactory answers easily on Google, but I'm trying to create a model that predicts whether an input belongs in 1 of X categories.

So multiple numeric explanatory -> non-binary categorical response variable

I've only learnt about linear and logistic regression in class, and I don't think either apply here. I've seen tutorials on random forests, is this what I'd have to use?

Comment: Logistic regression can be extended to more than two classes. Perhaps you should look up multinomial logistic regression.

Comment: Multiclass Support Vector Machines